# Website loading difficulties after TLD change from .com to .promo

Tags: dns, ssl, domain-name

We recently changed the URL of our website from `eyevertising.com` to `bold.promo`, and we now hear from a few random customers that they can't access the new website!

The only thing we really did, was swapping the domain that points to the existing website by updating both @ and www A records from our GoDaddy DNS admin panel. I couldn't replicate the issue and never had any issue accessing the new URL but obviously, some people do!

I can remember that some customers mentioned an unsecured connection warning from their browser even though we have a working SSL.

Can the issue be TLD-related? **Can the "exotic" `.promo` extension trigger issues that the `.com` doesn't**? If that is the case, we can switch to `boldpromo.com` and never hear from those issues again!

We've contacted GoDaddy many times, but they assure us that everything is in order on their side.

Comment: if you have HTTPS services, and you changed your domain, you likely need to have installed new certificates for the new domain, and reconfigure your sites to use them. does your webserver use SNI? if so, you likely need to reconfigure the SNI hostname on the site bindings. there is a lot to this, and its unlikely your config is simple and generic enough to just change the DNS records and be done.

Comment: also the change in the TLD likely has no more impact than any other DNS name change (eg blah.tld vs blah1.tld vs www.blah.tld). it is possible that some orgs black-hole some domains or TLDs, but that's not something under your control.

Comment: Did you lower the TTL before the change and then raise it back to normal afterwards? Try lowering it now and wait a day or so. It could simply be DNS servers not updating quickly enough. Lowering the TTL will help them pick up the changes. You mention SSL and that could mean HSTS is not set to pick up the change. Try to set HSTS headers to 0 so clients have to revalidate immediately and leave that setting for a few days. Then change it back to normal when things clear up.

Comment: Yes, exotic TLDs can cause problems with improperly configured DNS servers and/or bad/outdated software.

Comment: Check the propagation of your new DNS records here: https://dnschecker.org/

Comment: @BadHorsie DNS was changed 3 weeks ago... :(

Comment: @Giacomo1968 TTL was changed to 600s (10min) at the time of the DNS change, about 3 weeks ago. They are still set at that value though.

Comment: @sfaber Darn. Well, you definitely did the right thing. Next thing I would check is the HSTS related headers for the SSL issues. If you can change that to 0 (for browsers to clear SSL cached values) it might clear things up.